# How to add multiple lines in all files present in a directory using Ansible

Tags: ansible

In Ansible script, First I'm using find_module to find all files in a directory, and then I'm using set_fact to mention all commands that I want to add in all files and then I am using lineinfile module to add multiple lines in all the files, but it is adding all commands in list format ['line1','line2','line3'] instead of this I want these lines to be added one after another in all files.
Below mentioned is the script

```yaml
    tasks:
      - name: finding all files present in something directory
        find:
          paths: /etc/something.d/
          file_type: file
          patterns: '*.d'
        register: c1
        become: true
      - set_fact:
          lines:
          - "line1"
          - "line2"
          - "line3"
      - lineinfile:
          path: "{{ item.path }}"
          line: "{{ lines}}"
          state: present
          create: yes
          backup: yes
        register: c2
        become: true
        with_items: "{{ c1.files }}"
      - debug:
          var: c1
      - debug:
          var: c2
```

Comment: You have with_items two times ... check the doc about nested loop.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
tasks:
  - name: finding all files present in something directory
    find:
      paths: /etc/something.d/
      file_type: file
      patterns: '*.d'
    register: c1
    become: true
  - blockinfile:
      path: "{{ item.path }}"          
      state: present
      create: yes
      backup: yes
      block: |
        line1
        line1
        line1  
    register: c2
    become: true
    with_items: "{{ c1.files }}"
  - debug:
      var: c1
  - debug:
      var: c2
```

Answer (score 0):

So... the old way, which I prefer, is `with_nested`:

```
set_fact:
  lines:
    - line1
    - line2
    - line3

lineinfile:
  ...
  ...
with_nested:
  - "{{ c1.files }}"
  - "{{ lines }}"
```

The new way, and I have no idea what escapee from a Ph.D. CS program came up with this, is to combine the lists:

```
set_fact:
  lines:
    - line1
    - line2
    - line3

lineinfile:
  ...
  ...
loop: "{{ c1.files | product | lines | list }}"
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian

If all the lines are together, you might want to look at `blockinfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add multiple lines in all files present in a directory by using below mentioned ansible script, However the problem now is all lines are getting duplicated, if I run this script again, Please suggest any way so that lines won't get duplicated in all files

```yaml
    tasks:
      - name: finding all files present in something directory
        find:
          paths: /etc/something.d/
          file_type: file
          patterns: '*.d'
        register: c1
        become: true
      - set_fact:
          lines:
          - "line1"
          - "line2"
          - "line3"
      - lineinfile:
          path: "{{ item.path }}"
          line: "{{ lines[0]+'\n'+lines[1]+'\n'+lines[2]+'\n'}}"
          state: present
          create: yes
          backup: yes
        register: c2
        become: true
        with_items: "{{ c1.files }}"
      - debug:
          var: c1
      - debug:
          var: c2
```